# firefox ("$linkurl"); problem

Tags: linux, perl

can anyone tell me why firefox is not opening up with the below Net::HTTPServer lines added?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# v5.10.1 / linux
use strict;
use warnings;
use Shell;
use Net::HTTPServer;


############ section ###############
my $server = new Net::HTTPServer(
                                 port=>5000,
                                 docroot=>"/home/frank/Perl/perl_info_pages",
                                 log => "/home/frank/Perl/perl_info_pages/access.log",

                                 chroot => 0,        #       - Run the server behind a virtual chroot().
                                #  Since only root can actually call chroot,
                                #  a URL munger is provided that will not
                                #  allow URLs to go beyond the document root
                                #  if this is specified.
                                #   ( Default: 1 )  / true ???

                                # allow only for localhost... and user ***
                                # super server daemon control of??
                                # cgi...
                                  );

$server->Start();
$server->Process(); 
 ############# end of section ###################

 # can anyone tell me why these lines work(to open up firefox) with the above section commented out, but do not work when they are uncommented??
my $linkurl = 'http://localhost:5000';
firefox ("$linkurl");
```

Comment: What happens instead? Is that last line part of your Perl script? Do you have a `firefox` function defined?

Comment: Yes the last line is a part of my script.  I think the "use Shell;" is all that is needed for it to work(I have no function defined for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained into the HttpServer documentation, the `Process()` call is blocking and runs the server indefinitely, so the last two lines are never reached.

The simplest thing you could do is to spawn the Firefox process between the `Start` and the `Process`: the socket will be already created, and when the process spawning code will have returned the server will start running.

Comment: Thanks, those this mean I have to fork or thread the server part?  Sorry am new, hope this is alright to ask?

Comment: Either that, or simply create the Firefox process after the `Start`.

Answer (score 1):

[Net::HTTPServer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aHTTPServer)'s [Process](http://search.cpan.org/~reatmon/Net-HTTPServer-1.1.1/lib/Net/HTTPServer.pm#Process%28timeout%29) method never returns unless you give it a timeout.  If you want to print a message, you have to do it before calling Process.  You can do it after Start if you want to know what port the server has bound to.